# What does "direct-attached networks" mean?

Tags: ip, tcp

[This page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=tuning-tcp-maximum-segment-size) says the following:

> TCP controls this maximum size, known as Maximum Segment Size (MSS),
> for each TCP connection. For direct-attached networks, TCP computes
> the MSS by using the MTU size of the network interface and then
> subtracting the protocol headers to come up with the size of data in
> the TCP packet. For example, Ethernet with a MTU of 1500 would result
> in a MSS of 1460 after subtracting 20 bytes for IPv4 header and 20
> bytes for TCP header.

What does "direct-attached networks" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the network to which your host is directly attached. If you are directly attached to an ethernet network, then the MTU is 1500 octets. Different data-link protocols have different MTUs.